# Add reference of json file within jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iis, datatables

I have this in my web api application :

[image]

in `CaisseAssurance` script I used the [datatable plugin](https://www.datatables.net/)

```
var table = $('#tbl').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    //"language": { "url": "datatable.french.json" },
    "language": { "url": "../datatable.french.json" },
     "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 250, 500, -1], [50, 250, 500, "Tout"]],
    "destroy": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
                     { "width": "0.1%", "targets": 0 }
    ]
});
```

My problem is that the json file is not found (in the two cases)

```
  //"language": { "url": "datatable.french.json" },
    "language": { "url": "../datatable.french.json" },
```

> GET http://localhost:6460/datatable.french.json 404 (Not Found)

So I need to know :

1. What are the possible reasons of this?
2. How can I fix my code?

Comment: What's the URL of the page that runs/includes the `CaisseAssurance.js`?

Comment: http://localhost:6460/Configuration/CaisseAssurance

Comment: Can you test that `http://localhost:6460/Configuration/datatable.french.json` is accessible? When you specify an `url` to `$.ajax` it will be relative to the page. Using your commented-out URL should work - unless there's some datatable magic going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by adding this snippet in **web.config** file

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```